# BSOD on Windows 7 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod

I have a laptop that is encountering a BSOD. I have retrieved the mini dump and used WinDb to the best of my ability to figure out what is causing it. Would some please review my findings and help point me in the right direction?

```
3858 errors : !ataport (fffff8800115e000-fffff8800115efff)
MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption
IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE_4096
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE_4096
BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE_4096
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_memory_corruption_large_4096
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e2df8c99-e1e2-9063-1436-3db085e63f6e}
Followup: memory_corruption
```

Comment: You should provide some information by using BlueScreenView. This doesn't give a process name or anything and the information isn't extremely helpful. My first guess would be something with RAM. Running [MemTest86](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) can help you determine if RAM is the culprit or not.

Comment: @Dean Baldwin Can you please attach your minidump file to the question so others can view all the necessary data ?

Comment: @snaks20 how do I attach the file? I can't anywhere to attach it.

Comment: Upload somewhere trustworthy and link it.

Comment: You will find the minidump on my google drive here: <https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4caOJbOdX6nNUFlcjV6MkNmOUE/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: Anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking at your ATA.  Bad port, bad cable, bad connected device.  If you disconnect that as much as you can, does the blue screen goaway?  Probably won't boot since your drives are disconnected, but curious of the BSOD goes away.  You might only be able to remove the drives since this is a laptop however.

Comment: I believe ataport is something else: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/bsod-blue-screen-error/sys/windows/microsoft/windows-8-consumer-preview-iso-images/ataport-sys/

Comment: Laptops usually don't have data cables between HDD and motherboard.

Comment: @christopher The computer boots and functions fine. It just randomly blue screens and reboots the machine and then all is fine again.

Comment: @snaks20 "Laptops usually don't have data cables between HDD and motherboard" more do than you think.

Comment: @Moab I said *usually* , and i have dissasembled an old laptop with a cable between HDD and motherboard. If i'm wrong it's my mistake, sorry.

Comment: @MC10 - I did find that article, but .sys wasn't in the list and also listed memory problems.  My first instinct was to test the system memory and then I started looking at sATA problems.